# complex SQL query return result if AND not matched

Tags: mysql, sql

I wrote a complex SQL query (which) run correctly:

```
select user.id,user.name,profile.info,score.ammount
from user,profile,score
where email = 'example@email.com'
AND user.id = profile.user_id
AND user.id = score.user_id
AND profile.type = 'language'
AND score.type = 'amount'
```

this query will return :

```
[id] => 10002096
[name] => Erik
[info] => English
[ammount] => 510710
```

the problem is if user.id not matched with profile.user_id, the previous matched results like(user.id, user.name) not returned?  ( I want to return it even if next match not found)

if not matched want to return something like:

```
[id] => 10002096
[name] => Erik
```

how to fix this?

sample of profile table:

```
id          user_id    type         info  
1             1        language     english
2             1        admin        top  
3             2        likes        football
4             3        likes        -
5             3        language     english
```

user with id = 2 not has language

Comment: well without seeing any data my first reaction is 'Huh?' but maybe tyr changing some of the AND's to OR's? you should show some data for us to understand what you mean

Comment: You have a fundamental misunderstanding as to what AND means. In order for a result to be returned it must pass ALL of the AND statements.

Comment: Ditch the old-school comma syntax for a join operation. Use the JOIN keyword instead, and move the join predicates from the WHERE clause to the ON clause. That will enable you to do "outer" join operations with a `LEFT JOIN`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try left joining the tables instead of getting the Cartesian Product and filtering.. that is the old ansi way of joining tables and is more difficult to deal with as you add more tables.

```
SELECT u.id, u.name, p.info, s.ammount
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN profile p ON p.user_id = u.id AND p.type = 'language'
LEFT JOIN score s ON s.user_id = u.id AND s.type = 'amount'
WHERE email = 'example@email.com'
```

basically the left join says join the info and dont filter if there are rows that wont match

Comment: FYI the OP's query isn't a Cartesian result, they are just using "old" comma join syntax with the join conditions in the where clause.

Comment: @bluefeet I know.. sorry for not completely specifying that. its the old ansi way of doing it.. but generally not a good way to do it

Comment: it has the same problem (if p.type = 'language' not found) no result returned?

Comment: @mwafi can you provide some data then? give me a few rows one where the p.type is not language as well

Comment: @JohnRuddell there is no guarantee to find (type = language) in profile table (will update qustion)

Comment: you needed to filter the type and amount on the join condition instead of a where.. to show everything correctly :)